# Eigenvalue of the quotient of two $3\times3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two $3\times3$ real symmetric matrices $A,B$ and I want to find a real Eigenvalue of $AB^{-1}$.

Is there a better way (in terms of the number of operations) than to form $AB^{-1}$ explicitly (by solving a triple $3\times3$ system) and compute a real Eigenvalue from the characteristic polynomial ?

---

**Update:**

From the answer by @Robert, it is better to compute the polynomial $\det(A-\lambda B)$, which can be expanded as

$$|a_0\ a_1\ a_2|
\\-(|b_0\ a_1\ a_2|+|a_0\ b_1\ a_1|+|a_0\ a_2\ b_2|)\lambda
\\+(|a_0\ b_1\ b_2|+|b_0\ a_1\ b_2|+|b_0\ b_1\ a_2|)\lambda^2
\\-|b_0\ b_1\ b_2|\lambda^3.$$

We can spare some determinant evaluations by computing for $\lambda=0,\infty,1,-1$ and reconstructing the polynomial by these four points.

Comment: Haven't worked it out, but I'm thinking you could use the fact that symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable.

Comment: [this discussion on math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106191/eigenvalues-of-the-product-of-two-symmetric-matrices) might be of some help

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: right, but in general they are not simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: Since your concern is to reduce no. of operations, you can compute $B^{-1}$ using LU factorization. It will reduce some steps?

Comment: @Koro: this was implicit in "by solving a triple $3\times3$ system".

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Ahh Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\det(AB^{-1} - \lambda I) = \det(A - \lambda B)/\det(B)$, I would just look at the cubic polynomial $\det(A-\lambda B)$.
Maple tells me that for $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices, the coefficients can be computed with $48$ multiplications and $26$ additions: I don't know if that is optimal.

```
t38 = a[2, 3], 
t47 = 2*t38, 
t34 = b[1, 3], 
t35 = b[1, 2], 
t46 = t34*t35, 
t39 = a[2, 2], 
t41 = a[1, 2], 
t42 = a[1, 1], 
t45 = t39*t42 - t41^2, 
t40 = a[1, 3], 
t44 = -t34*t41 - t35*t40, 
t33 = b[2, 2], 
t36 = b[1, 1], 
t43 = t33*t42 - 2*t35*t41 + t36*t39, 
t37 = a[3, 3], 
t32 = b[2, 3], 
t31 = b[3, 3], 
t29 = t40^2, 
t28 = t38^2, 
t27 = t35^2, 
t26 = t34^2, 
t25 = t32^2, 
p[0] = t40*t41*t47 - t28*t42 - t29*t39 + t37*t45, 
p[1] = t28*t36 + t29*t33 - t45*t31 - t43*t37 + 2*(-t32*t41 + t34*t39)*t40 + (t32*t42 + t44)*t47, 
p[2] = t46*t47 - t25*t42 - t26*t39 - t27*t37 + (-2*t34*t40 + t36*t37)*t33 + 2*(-t36*t38 - t44)*t32 + t43*t31, 
p[3] = -2*t32*t46 + t25*t36 + t26*t33 + (-t33*t36 + t27)*t31
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. I like that one because it avoids matrix inversion (and divisions). It is an easy matter to see that the extreme coefficients are $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$, which would already consume $24$ mults and $10$ adds. For the others, I don't know.